# PHP Contact Form Blank Data & Unknown Sender

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I have made a contact form on my website but even if the user doesn't type in any of the details and presses the submit button it sends me a blank email with nothing in it from Unknown Sender.

Anyone know why this is happening? I have added form validation so it shouldn't be sending anything.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<font color="red">*</font> Name <input type="text" name="name" required>
<font color="red">*</font> Phone <input type="text" name="phone" required>
<font color="red">*</font> Email <input type="text" name="email" required>
<font color="red">*</font> Message <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="I am looking for..." required><br />
<input type="image" src="images/Landing_Pages/submit.png" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $preferred = $_POST['preferred'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Message: $message \n Preferred Contact: $preferred \n Email: $email";
    $recipient = "bwebb@webbmaster.com.au";
    $subject = "New Request Southbank";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: you need to use a conditional statement `!empty()` for all your inputs. Someone's not filling one or more fields.

Comment: missing `$message=$_POST['message']` in your code!!!

Comment: Do i just add that code into each input field?

Comment: *"I have added form validation so it shouldn't be sending anything."* - oh, where?

Comment: seems like you're not paying attention to comments, or just not bothering answering to them, ^^^ well the one above anyway. which tells me you're not showing us full code for the "validation" as you stated.

Answer (score 4):

You have to check if post data is not empty

```
 if (!empty($name) && !empty($phone) && !empty($preferred) && !empty($email)) {
      mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
 }
```

**Edit**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $preferred = $_POST['preferred'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Message: $message \n Preferred Contact: $preferred \n Email: $email";
    $recipient = "bwebb@webbmaster.com.au";
    $subject = "New Request Southbank";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($phone) && !empty($message) && !empty($preferred) && !empty($email)) {
        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi phplover where abouts do I add this code? In the HTML or PHP code?

Comment: @EndôFujimoto in the php code, place mail() function inside the if statement

Comment: <?php $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $preferred = $_POST['preferred'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n

Comment: Message: $message \n Preferred Contact: $preferred \n Email: $email";
    $recipient = "bwebb@webbmaster.com.au";
    $subject = "New Request Southbank";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($phone) && !empty($preferred) && !empty($email)) {
      mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
 }
    ?>

Comment: Still having issues mate. Could you let me know if this code is correct?

Comment: @EndôFujimoto use the code I put in the answer after **editing**

Comment: @phplover Look at part of OP's statement in the question: *I have added form validation so it shouldn't be sending anything."* - this tells me they're not showing us their full code, probably using some JS somewhere. Yet, OP didn't reply to my comment under the question, hence my not submitting an answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I could not see any validation in that code, maybe he did not notice that he forgot to do it.

Comment: @phplover I'm guessing that it's playing a part in all this and as to why we haven't seen your answer accepted. Your answer in theory, should work.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like :

```
$errorflag = 0 ;
if(empty($name)){$errorflag = 1 ;$error = "Input your Name plz!"; }; 
if(empty($phone)){$errorflag = 1 ;$error = "Input phone"; }
...
if(!$errorflag) {
    @mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
}
```

check every input you need and then send

Comment: As `saty` said ADD `$message=$_POST['message']` in yout code too